# Google api v3 calandar quickadd php

Tags: php, google-api

I'm trying to create events in my google calendar with the google quickadd API.
Here is my code:

```
require_once 'googleapi/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google\Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Google Calendar API");
$client->setDeveloperKey("AIzaSyDdR3w2J59ZVVv_s7BopzNuteu1Bzo");
$client->setAuthConfig('googleapi/code_secret_client_62725432848-um1gbjoo7iqi1upvmv4niosddfte43.apps.googleusercontent.com.json');
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events");

$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
// echo "<pre>";
// print_r($service);
// echo "</pre>";
$createdEvent = $service->events->quickAdd(
    'myemail@gmail.com',
    'Appointment at Somewhere on June 3rd 10am-10:25am'
);

echo $createdEvent->getId();
```

I keep getting the error below. Can someone please tell me why?

Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: { "error": { "code": 401, "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.%22), "errors": [ { "message": "Login Required.", "domain": "global", "reason": "required", "location": "Authorization", "locationType": "header" } ], "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED" } } in C:\xampp\htdocs\google quick add\googleapi\src\Http\REST.php:128 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\google quick add\googleapi\src\Http\REST.php(103): Google\Http\REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...') #1 [internal function]: Google\Http\REST::doExecute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\google quick add\googleapi\src\Task\Runner.php(18 in C:\xampp\htdocs\google quick add\googleapi\src\Http\REST.php on line 128

Comment: As you're getting 401 exception, I'd check wether the credentials are in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to error messages you weren't authorized.

[these you can read about 401 HTTP code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401)

[And these you can see the example, right way to authorize your app](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#authentication-with-oauth)